# What is the Big O Time Complexity of this code?

Tags: python, time-complexity, big-o

I was wondering if someone could please explain what the time complexity is for the code below. I think it would be O(n) because the algorithm will take as much time to execute as there are elements in n.

```
sample_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 5, 6]                                          
check_list = []                                                                 
for i in sample_list:                                                           
  if i not in check_list:                                                       
    check_list.append(i)                                                        
  else:
    print(i,end='')
```

Comment: A good title is _unique to one specific problem_. There's an infinite number of different questions that could be in the body matching with the title "what is the big-O time complexity of this code?"

Comment: Beyond that, theoretical computer science is off-topic here; [cs.se] is the Stack Exchange site for it. Stack Overflow is strictly limited to questions about specific, narrow problems encountered in the course of writing code. "Why is implementation of the Foo algorithm, that should be O(log n), instead behaving as if it's O(n)?" is likely to be on-topic here; "what is the big-O time complexity of this code?" is a lot iffier.

Comment: ... but yes it is O(n)

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it belongs to https://cs.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

If you call yourself cs-student people will wonder if they are answering your homework questions for you. Having said that, your answer is wrong for it does not take into account the time complexity of the test (`if i not in check_list`). I leave the time complexity of that operation as an exercise to the reader.

Comment: I wondered when someone was going to bring up ```in```. The code as written is not O(n).

Comment: I would also mention that the `in` operation per se is not the real problem here. Indeed, if we had `if i in check_list` then the complexity would indeed be O(n) (with `check_list` being an empty list at the beginning).